# How to add Rubymine icon to the left top panel in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rubymine

Sorry, I'm new on Ubuntu, and I've got some problem: I installed RubyMine, moved it to /opt/RubyMine and executed it through /opt/Rubymine/bin/rubymine.sh. But how can I add this app to left panel instead of diving into system folders each time? I tried use "Lock to Launcher", but it didn't work (After closing I clicked by icon but there were no actions). So, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 42):

1. In Rubymine menu go to:

   `Tools -> Create Desktop Entry...`
2. This will create an application shortcut from the system menu.
3. Close your Rubymine instance, go to the system menu and type 'Rubymine' - you should see the Rubymine icon under the 'Applications' section. (**If you don't see the RubyMine shorcut logout and login of your session and it should now appear**)
4. Click it to open the application
5. Use the Right Click menu on the RubyMine icon and select 'Lock the Launcher'

It should work fine now.

Comment: I had to use the option `Create entry for all users` and then reboot (not just sign out) before the 'Lock to Launcher' would "stick".  (The launcher would be 'locked', but It kept starting an older version of Rubymine.)

Comment: No such option in Rubymine 2018

Answer (score 1):

Run `mine` on command line. If `mine` doesn't exist in `/usr/bin`, create a link using

```
ln -s /opt/Rubymine/bin/rubymine.sh /usr/bin/mine
```

Comment: In newer versions of Rubymine you can just use `Tools -> Create Command-line Launcher`.